# Como enviar dados para um formulário utilizando cURL?

Tags: php, formulário, libcurl

Estava lendo sobre o cURL, e vi que posso utiliza-lo para enviar dados para um formulário (como se estivesse digitando os dados e dando submit).

De que forma poderia fazer isso em php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode enviar uma requisição utilizando a biblioteca **[cURL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)** desta forma: uma vez definido um *array* de *chave-valor* com os seus parâmetros:

```
$fields = array('foo' => 'bar');
```

Você realiza a requisição para a `$url`:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

E obtém o resultado (caso exista) na variável `$result`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta ;)

Answer (score 2):

`cURL 'http://website.dom' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'data=valor&data2=valor2' -v`

`cURL` o comando em si.
`'http://website.dom'` o site para/path para onde o POST vai
`-X POST` diz ao cURL para usar o POST
`-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` mete um HTTP Header a avisar o servidor que o tipo de data é de um formulário
`--data 'string'` envia os dados
`-v` verbose

---

Conforme a [documentação de php sobre o curl_ini()](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) a forma mais básica de fazer um cURL em php é a seguinte:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @MoshMage, porém precisava de um exemplo em php. (Tinha esquecido deste detalhe na pergunta mas já a editei)>

Comment: @GWER Editado :)

Comment: Muito obrigado :P (+1)